# JavaScript code wont execute but get printed as part of html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html code with js inside and every time i submit the js wont execute but get printed as html, saw many similar problems on stack overflow they said something about not closing `<div>` correctly but i cant find the error on my code

This is  my html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row" id="riparues_frm">
<form method="post" action="ruajRiparues.php" id="FormaRuaj_rp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="idRiparues" id="idRiparues" />
    <div class="form-group row d-flex" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" >
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="Kerko skript sipas pershkrimit" onclick="lookUpBox({
                title: 'Kerko skript sipas pershkrimit',
                url: 'kerkoSkript_sipas_emrit.php?chars=',
                onItemSelected: function(data){
                   $('input[id=' +
                    'idRiparues]').val(data.idRiparues);
                $('#delref').attr('href','fshi_riparues.php?id=' + data.idRiparues);
                $('input[name=kodi]').val(data.kodi);
                $('input[name=seq]').val(data.sequenca);
                $('input[name=pershkrimi]').val(data.pershkrimi);
                $('#scripti').val(data.script);
                $('#scripti').load(data.script, resizeArea);
                $('#modelScripti').val(data.modelScript);
                $('#modelScripti').load(data.modelScript, resizeArea);

               $('#dataregj').val(data.datazgjedh);
               $('#tipi').val(data.Tipi);

               //kosta070622 start
                var checkTipi = data.Tipi;
                **filter()**
            //kosta070622 end
                },
                tableHeader: ['idRiparues','kodi', 'pershkrimi','sequenca','script','modelScript','data']
              })
            " />&nbsp

        </div>
```

and this is my js code:

```
 <script>
            function filter() {
                if(isadmin === 1){
                    if(checkTipi != 'S' && checkTipi != 'B'){
                        document.getElementById('modelScripti').hidden = true;
                        document.getElementById('pathi').hidden = false;
                        document.getElementById('myfile').hidden = false;
                        document.getElementById('seq').disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById('lblpershkrimi').innerHTML = 'Emri Skedarit';
                        document.getElementById('lblscript').innerHTML = 'Pathi Relativ';
                        document.getElementById('lblmodelscript').innerHTML = 'Model Pathi Relativ';
                        $('#pathi').val(data.modelScript);
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById('modelScripti').hidden = false;
                        document.getElementById('pathi').hidden = true;
                        document.getElementById('myfile').hidden = true;
                        document.getElementById('seq').disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById('lblpershkrimi').innerHTML = 'Pershkrimi';
                        document.getElementById('lblscript').innerHTML = 'Script';
                        document.getElementById('lblmodelscript').innerHTML = 'Model Script';
                    }

                }else{
                    if(checkTipi != 'S' && checkTipi != 'B'){
                        document.getElementById('modelScripti').hidden = true;
                        document.getElementById('pathi').hidden = false;
                        document.getElementById('myfile').hidden = true;
                        document.getElementById('seq').disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById('pathi').disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById('scripti').disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById('Edito').disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById('lblpershkrimi').innerHTML = 'Emri Skedarit';
                        document.getElementById('lblscript').innerHTML = 'Pathi Relativ';
                        document.getElementById('lblmodelscript').innerHTML = 'Model Pathi Relativ';

                        $('#pathi').val(data.modelScript);
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById('modelScripti').hidden = false;
                        document.getElementById('pathi').hidden = true;
                        document.getElementById('myfile').hidden = true;
                        document.getElementById('seq').disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById('scripti').disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById('Edito').disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById('lblpershkrimi').innerHTML = 'Pershkrimi';
                        document.getElementById('lblscript').innerHTML = 'Script';
                        document.getElementById('lblmodelscript').innerHTML = 'Model Script';
                    }
                }
                console.log(Boolean(isadmin));
                console.log("HYRI KETU");

            }
        </script>
```

The html code it was written by someone else i just added the function filter and thats the the code that is being printed as html on the website.

[image]

Comment: I have never seen so much script in a onclick attribute in my life!! but that doesn't even seem to be the issue - for some reason your `<script>` tag is being ignored

Comment: @Bravo as i said the html code was made by someone else i only added the filter function. Any idea why is being ignored?

Comment: `i only added the filter function.` how? it seems like your `<script>` tag is treated as some other type of tag - in the context of the code you posted, where did you put the script tag?

Comment: @Bravo check on html for this  `**filter()**`

Comment: Maybe there is a Stylesheet somewhere overriding the client style for the script element (`display:none`)

Comment: The `&nbsp` should end with a semi colon `&nbsp;`

Comment: @yunzen before i wrote my script inside the onlcick and this error was appearing random but since i moved it out and delcared the function inside check on html for this  `**filter()**` the error appears all the time now.

Comment: @testedwho - why? that's not the script ... are you putting `<script>` inside the onclick string? I asked where you put the script, not where you call the function inside the script

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are **missing 3 div closing tags**, and that is why your script is being read as html.

```
//1<div class="container-fluid">

//2<div class="row" id="riparues_frm">
<form method="post" action="ruajRiparues.php" id="FormaRuaj_rp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="idRiparues" id="idRiparues" />
   //3 <div class="form-group row d-flex" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" >
       //4 <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="Kerko skript sipas pershkrimit" onclick="lookUpBox({
                title: 'Kerko skript sipas pershkrimit',
                url: 'kerkoSkript_sipas_emrit.php?chars=',
                onItemSelected: function(data){
                   $('input[id=' +
                    'idRiparues]').val(data.idRiparues);
                $('#delref').attr('href','fshi_riparues.php?id=' + data.idRiparues);
                $('input[name=kodi]').val(data.kodi);
                $('input[name=seq]').val(data.sequenca);
                $('input[name=pershkrimi]').val(data.pershkrimi);
                $('#scripti').val(data.script);
                $('#scripti').load(data.script, resizeArea);
                $('#modelScripti').val(data.modelScript);
                $('#modelScripti').load(data.modelScript, resizeArea);

               $('#dataregj').val(data.datazgjedh);
               $('#tipi').val(data.Tipi);

               //kosta070622 start
                var checkTipi = data.Tipi;
                filter()
            //kosta070622 end
                },
                tableHeader: ['idRiparues','kodi', 'pershkrimi','sequenca','script','modelScript','data']
              })
            " />&nbsp   
       //1 </div>          
    //2 </div> //this and below are added by me
   //3</form>
  //4 </div>
 //5 </div>
```

Comment: i will check it now and let you know

Comment: that wouldn't cause a `<script>` tag to be treated as something other than a script tag

Comment: No didnt work and it ruins the design of html

Comment: My bad, </forn> tag was missing as well, I added it. That was the reason for ruining design.